# How to add an ssh-tunnelled remote to an existing repo?

Tags: git, ssh, repository, remote-server, ssh-tunnel

I have a local repo on my laptop which already has a remote called `origin`. Apart from my laptop and `origin`, there is a third machine called `remote1` which I want to add as another remote to my local repo. What I do on my laptop is

```bash
    git remote add remote1
    git remote set-url remote1 ssh://sshUser@remote1Address:path/to/.git
```

But when doing so, the command
`git push remote1 branchName`
gives

```bash
  ssh: connect to host remote1Address port 22: Connection timed out.
```

Accessing remote1 through `ssh` is possible only through
a jump proxy. `Port 22` being closed is the main reason behind using a jump proxy in this
case; Here is my
`.ssh/config`

```bash
Host jumpProxy
    Hostname jumpProxyAddress
    User jumpUser

Host remote1
    Hostname remote1Address
    User sshUser
    ProxyJump jumpUser@jumpProxyAddress
```

so I guess
the source of the problem is that the jump proxy is not called at all, that
is, `.ssh/config` is not read at all. What solution do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things wrong with your `git remote set-url` statement:

1. You've defined a specific hostname for `remote1` in `~/.ssh/config` with the proxy and user details, but you aren't using it.
2. The URL format is incorrect: if you're going to use `ssh://` then there should be a slash between the `user@host` details and the repository path (not a colon).

You should be able to fix both with a single statement: `git remote set-url remote1 ssh://remote1/path/to/.git`. (Note that there's no `user@` there; it's defined in your `~/.ssh/config`.)